# AC to terminal block relays

Tags: voltage, power, relay, terminal

How can I use one power cable to connect to 4 relays in parallel?

So for example, I have one power cable and I want to turn on 3 radiators out for 4.

This is my screenshot of the circuit.

[image]

Terminal 4 and 3 for each would be connected AC and 2 and 1 would be the radiator.

Comment: For clarity, you want to have one connector to replace U1 to U4 and interface with K1 to K4? Do you need to keep it as a four-pin connector, or could you use five? Also, do all the relays have the same switching voltage?

Comment: Yes one connector and each individual radiator has it's one relay which has the same switching voltage of 5V. I just want to use one plug to power the radiators. So I can turn on radiator 1 and 3 or just 1 etc.

Comment: the relays in the schematic are incorrectly drawn ... the signals to and from the relays should be connected to the end of the red pins, not to the relay outline ... similar to the U1 connector